# Set multiple values for an element in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I am new to schema design.

I am trying to set multiple values to a element in XML like shown below:

```
<EVENT>SYS_EVENT, TEMP_EVENT </EVENT>
```

I tried various schema designs for element `EVENT`  using lists, enumeration etc.

But quite unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried white spaces instead of comma, still it sets single value.

I would really appreciate any help.

I am using Altova XMLSpy for schema design.

```
<xs:element name="EVENT">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="SYS_EVT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CON_MGT_EVT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PWR_MGT_EVT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="TEMP_EVT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="APP_MGT_EVT"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="CFG_MGT_EVT"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:list>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close -- just two simple changes to make:

1. Use spaces, not commas, between list members.
2. Be careful to match spelling exactly: SYS_**EVENT** vs SYS_**EVT**, etc.

So, if you leave your XSD as is and change your XML,

```
<EVENT>SYS_EVT TEMP_EVT</EVENT>
```

then the XML will validate successfully against your XSD.

Comment: Hi kjhughes, I tried like you suggested, but am still not able to select more that one value. When I select the second value,  it overwrites the first one.

Comment: *Select?*   XSD is for validation, not selection.   The changes I described will allow your XML to be validated successfully against your XSD.  To speak of *selecting more than one value* is something that XPath would do, or is something that a UI to an application that uses XSD might enable in editing XML.  You mention using XMLSpy for schema design.  Are you actually asking a question about how the XMLSpy XML editor works, perhaps, when you ask about selecting values?

Comment: I successfully validated the xml against the xsd. My idea was to be able to set multiple values to a single element in the xml. Sorry for the confusion. For EVENT element,  I wanted more than one value.

Comment: But I show more than one value in `EVENT` in my answer:  `SYS_EVT` and  `TEMP_EVT`.  That XML validates successfully against your XSD.  I'm sorry, but I must be misunderstanding still.  Do you perhaps mean that you want more than one `EVENT` *element*?

Comment: <EVENT>SYS_EVT TEMP_EVT</EVENT>  This is what I need. I set <EVENT>SYS_EVT, but when I try to set TEMP_EVT as well, the element becomes <EVENT>TEMP_EVT</EVENT>, while I was expecting <EVENT>SYS_EVT TEMP_EVT</EVENT>. I must be missing something.

Comment: What program are you using when you say "I set" and "the element becomes"?

Comment: In the xml file. It auto populates values and prompts enumerations. I am using Altova for creating xml files as well.

Comment: This answer resolves the general XML and XSD issue.  What remains then is a question for Altova technical support.  I don't have their product or support problems with it.  Good luck.